# Automated Testing for testers with no coding required

Tags: selenium, testing, tfs, azure-devops, automated-tests

I'm trying to improve the testing process where I work, but without adjusting the structure.

What we have: VSTS, Selenium IDE, Testers who write test cases, but not code.

What I'd like to do is manage a way to marry our TFS continuous integration with the Selenium tests we write.  These are **NOT** the code-driven selenium tests, but rather the IDE version where users click through, and set assertions using the IDE (All are just UI tests).  I know we can export those tests plans as a .SIDE file, but what I can't figure out, is how to have our TFS server execute those as part of a deployment or build pipeline.

Ideally, developers/devops would setup projects in TFS from the onset with whatever solution makes sense to execute these Selenium .SIDE files, but afterwards, the testers would manage adding/modifying those tests cases elsewhere.

The real goal here is to not have testers writing code, or checking in code.  Only writing these UI Selenium tests, but having TFS execute those as part of CI.

Researching this on the internet drives me basically always to something that requires testers to write code.

Comment: if you can run Java on your server, you might consider my hobby project: https://www.browsermator.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can automate testing without code, at lease, you need a test project containing your automated tests.

Generally, in Azure DevOps, we use `Visual Studio Test task` to run tests. This task supports using the following tests:

- **Test assembly**: Use this option to specify one or more test assemblies that contain your tests. You can optionally specify a
  filter criteria to select only specific tests.
- **Test plan**: Use this option to run tests from your test plan that have an automated test method associated with it. To learn more about
  how to associate tests with a test case work item, see [Associate
  automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops).
- **Test run**: Use this option when you are setting up an environment to [run tests from test plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops). This option should not be used when
  running tests in a continuous integration/continuous deployment
  (CI/CD) pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

This was a question that I had as well, and I think I found an imperfect but better solution.

I wasn't able to get my Selenium IDE tests running with Jenkins, but I was able to get them to run with TeamCity, another CI.
I created a build step like the following :

- **Runner type:** Command Line
- **Working Directory:** where the selenium IDE .side file is located
- **Run:** Custom Script
- With the build script content that I usually use to run my Selenium IDE Tests, such as `selenium-side-runner sidefile.side`
- I also added the following so I could output the results in Junitor another form: `--output-directory=results --output-format=junit`
- You can also add the following so the tests are run headlessly, this only works in Chrome : `-c "goog:chromeOptions.args=[--headless,--nogpu] browserName=chrome"`
- Finally, I also use `--filter` to run one test suite at a time, but that is optional too.
- I then used another build step to export the results to our test manger, xray, but I think that is beyond the scope of this question.

The problem with this solution is that it runs directly from a users individual machine still, but this can be work around.